# Suggest a reasonable approach to combine the following variables into a single vector

Tags: variable, composite

I have 9 variables, namely BMI, waist-to-hip ratio (WHR), healthy-diet (HD: a score of 0 to 4, close to 4 indicates healthy), waist circumference (WC), neuroticism score (NS), body fat percentage (BF), physical activity (PA: total MET score data obtained from uk biobank), pack years of smoking (SMK) and alcohol intake frequency (ALC: a score from 0 to 5 where 5 indicates highest intake). I want to meaningfully combine these vectors of variables in one vector. I tried standardising and getting the simple addition.

1. I need to know whether the scaled sum approach is valid, and if yes, some references
2. I need to know a few other options to make an all-in-one variable, since these 9 variables are particularly not falling under one category. It's very difficult to give a common name to the newly composite variable, but I have no choice. I'm looking for a valid approach to combine them (with references).
3. I do not want to go for a variable reduction technique such as PCA or factor analysis, but I need an all-in-one variable.

More details:

After producing this all-in-one variable, I would fit this as a single covariate in genome-wide-environment-interaction-study (GWEIS) with a binary scale phenotype using the R package "GxEprs", and then use the same variable in predicting the genomic risk scores in the target (independent) sample, using Model 5 given in GxEprs package.

Package source: https://github.com/DoviniJ/GxEprs

Comment: It really looks to me like you need a PCA and 2 variables, not one. Why is it that you cannot ?

Comment: What do you intend to do with this "all-in-one variable" after you produce it? Please edit the question to provide that information, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.

Comment: @Caroz I'm looking for a valid approach to combine all those variables as a single vector, which is why PCA would not fit me.

Comment: @EdM This is for genomic research. I will edit the question adding details.

Comment: @Caroz I tried PCA, but as per my requirement, I can consider only one PC. There the maximum variance explained is given by the 1st PC. So is it reasonable to use only the 1st PC in that case? The variance I got was only 47% from the 1st PC